# I am trying to post the data into HTTP but I am getting formGroup expects a FormGroup instance error

Tags: angular

> CreateCollegeComponent.html:4 ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

Example:

```
<div [formGroup]="myGroup">
  <input formControlName="firstName">
</div>
```

In your class:

```
this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
   firstName: new FormControl()
});
```

> ```
> at Function.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.ReactiveErrors.missingFormException (forms.js:1169)
> at FormGroupDirective.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormGroupDirective._checkFormPresent (forms.js:4598)
> at FormGroupDirective.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormGroupDirective.ngOnChanges (forms.js:4508)
> at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:9239)
> at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:10507)
> at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:10469)
> ```

Comment: have you import FormsModule in your main module "import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';"

Comment: I have all ready imported the FormsModule

Comment: Page is rendering before `myGroup` is instantiated. Add `*ngIf="myGroup"` attribute to the `div` or a parent element.

Comment: You can do this in constructor 
this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
   firstName: new FormControl()
}); or you can refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43669773/angular-2-formgroup-expects-a-formgroup-instance-please-pass-one-in

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I defined the form inside ngOnInit. Move that to constructor and the issue gets resolved.