# Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance when dynamically creating a Reactive form using in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, form-control, angular-formbuilder

I have 2 components. My parent component html is

```
<app-child *ngIf="info.length>0" [info]="info"></app-child>
```

This is my child component.

```
@Input() info: Info[];
fieldForm: FormGroup;

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    console.log(this.info);    
  }

ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    if (this.info.length > 0 ) {
      this.createFieldForm();
    }
  }

 private createFieldForm() {
   const group = {};
    this.info.forEach(field => {
      group[field.label] = new FormControl('');
    });
    this.fieldForm = new FormGroup(group);

}
```

My info response is like this that coming from api.

```
const info = [
  {
    "type":"textBox",
    "label":"Name",
  },
  {
    "type":"number",
    "label":"Age"
  }
]
```

This is my child component html

```
<form [formGroup]="fieldForm">
  <div *ngFor="let field of info">
   <div [ngSwitch]="field.type">
     <div *ngSwitchCase="'textBox'">
      <input type="text" formControlName="{{field.label}}"/>
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'number'">
      <input type="number" formControlName="{{field.label}}"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

If I use `<ng-template *ngIf="info.length>0">` in html then this error does n't show. But I can't see the form.

```
Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43669773/angular-2-formgroup-expects-a-formgroup-instance-please-pass-one-in)

Comment: @Brandon `Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance`  this error solved. But child component html doesn't render.

Comment: @Brandon `Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: '[object Object]'.` Now this error is coming. Since I am using `ngAfterViewChecked()`

Comment: That happens when an object has been changed after initial change detection has run. I would move the code currently in `ngAfterViewChecked` to `ngOnInit` or possibly to `ngOnChanges`

Comment: @Hans does your issue been resolved?