# call function and have the value placed in angular form group

Tags: angular, function, subscription

I have an issue which I am puzzled for quite a while. It most be very simple, but I am super stuck.

The issue is, I have a function:

```
    public getListTitle(): any {
    const listId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('listId');
    console.log("het list-id = " + listId);
    this.listService.getListNo404(listId).subscribe(list=>{
    this.listTitle= list.listTitle ;
    console.log(this.listTitle);
    });
    console.log(this.listTitle);
    return this.listTitle;
  }
```

And I would like to have the listTitle element passed in my fb group:

```
{
    
    this.newList = this.fb.group({
      'listTitle': [this.getListTitle()],
      'listId':['873'],
      'listCreator':[this.username],
      'sublist': this.fb.array([
        this.initSublist() 
      ])
    });
```

However I am just not able to make it work. Tried all kinds of things with map and subscribe, but something clearly does not click in my mind yet.

I also see in the console that the first console.log does print the desired value, however the second doesn't. So something is going wrong in the subscription.

Thanks a lot for having a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the observable from the function and subscribe to it where it's response is required.

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

public getListTitle(): Observable<any> {
  const listId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('listId');
  return this.listService.getListNo404(listId).pipe(
    map((list) => list.listTitle)   // <-- use `map` operator to return `listTitle`
  );
}
```

And use the observable

```js
this.getListTitle().subscribe({
  next: (listTitle: any) => {
    this.newList = this.fb.group({
      'listTitle': [listTitle],
      'listId':['873'],
      'listCreator':[this.username],
      'sublist': this.fb.array([
        this.initSublist() 
      ])
    });
  },
  error: (error: any) => {
    // handle errors
  }
});
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/6513921) to learn why you'd need to do it this way.

Comment: Thanks so much, got it working now!! Will dive into the background! 

Had a new issue which I managed to solve by adding an *ngIf in the template, this helped:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43669773/angular-2-formgroup-expects-a-formgroup-instance-please-pass-one-in