# Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form', in Angular 12

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot

i got an issue that was already addressed here.

```
Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.
```

I added as explain ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModules in the required modules by issue is not solved

**view.html**

```
  <form formGroup="siteForm" (ngSubmit)="createNewSite()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Nom du site</label>
      <input type="text" formControlName="siteName" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    ...
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Envoyer</button>
  </form>
```

**site.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CreateComponent} from './create/create.component';
import {ReadComponent} from './read/read.component';
import {BrowserModule} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from "@angular/forms";


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CreateComponent,
    ReadComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ]
})
export class SiteModule {
}
```

**create.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create',
  templateUrl: './create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create.component.scss']
})
export class CreateComponent implements OnInit {

  siteForm!: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.siteForm = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        siteName: ['', [Validators.required]],
        siteDescription: ['', [Validators.required]],
        siteCreatedOn: ['', [Validators.required]],
        siteActive: ['', [Validators.required]]
      }
    );
  }

  createNewSite() {
    console.log(this.siteForm.value);
  }

}
```

I removed 'ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModules' from all modules and the put it back in all module.ts file but it didn't solve the issue

Any idea?
Thx!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43669773/angular-2-formgroup-expects-a-formgroup-instance-please-pass-one-in)

Comment: I think your implemented lazy loading, `CreateComponent` declared under `site.module.ts` so need to add in site module, also no need to add on app.module.ts

Comment: @BrandonTaylor, unfortunately not :(

Comment: @hrdkisback yes it's declared under site.module, and Forms are only declared under site and not app, anyway, i can put Forms everywehere it does not change anything

Answer (score 0):

First of all, is view.html same as create.component.html?
if yes, change
`<form formGroup="siteForm" (ngSubmit)="createNewSite()">` to `<form [formGroup]="siteForm" (ngSubmit)="createNewSite()">` and you have to import `ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModules`

Comment: also `formGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});` in your TS

Comment: yes `view.html` is `create.component.html` put the wrong name file.
`formGroup="siteForm"` compile fine, `[formGroup]="siteForm"` give me the error.
`ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModules` are imported in the file `site.module.ts`

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found my error.
`siteModule` was not declared in the `entities/entities.module.ts` which is the parent folder of `site [entities/site/site.module.ts]`!

Thx for you answers anyway:)

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that I didn't declare components in module declarations: [yourComponent]